# TSQL query for transactional replication log reader agent account in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, replication

What is the TSQL query to fetch transactional replication log reader agent account in SQL Server?

I can get the information in SSMS UI, from:
Replication->Local Publication->Pick a publication->Right Click Properties->Agent Security

I'm unable to find this info in any of the system tables in the distribution database.

I need the info for an automation script.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `MSsnapshot_agents` and `MSlogreader_agents` tables created in the distribution database. The Snapshot and Log Reader job_id's can be obtained and used to gather information about the job such as which database principal is associated with the job. It appears that account info is also stored in the tables above.

You can use the job_id from the table above to get extra info from the Agent Job, such as database principal.

```
SELECT    
    JOB.job_id AS JobID,
    JOB.[name] AS JobName,
    PRIN.[name] AS Principal
FROM
    msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS JOB
    LEFT JOIN msdb.sys.database_principals AS PRIN ON JOB.owner_sid = PRIN.sid
WHERE
   JOB.job_id = @X
```

Comment: Although I see a publisher_login column in both tables, it is empty in my case.

Comment: @RaviLobo Are you saying the publisher_login is null, or the table returns no records? If the former, then you can use the added query above to get the principal running a job. This would be synonymous with the user selected in the configuration wizard.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Table does have records, only the column publisher_login is null. Even in the above query I get  NULL for for Principal. It might be the way replication is set-up in our case. We are using a proxy account to run the SQL job. So the owner of the job is not replication agent account.

Comment: hmm, ok, not sure then. If you are using a dedicated distributer, you can try looking on that machine too. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Although, I didn't find a straight forward TSQL, I found 2 alternative ways.

Option 1:

```
Use myPublisheddb
exec sp_helplogreader_agent
```

The proc returns a table; with some tweaking we can get the required info.

Option 2:

```
select * from master.sys.credentials
```

Same here. Returns a table, which can be mined for the right data.